# Simply Connected Complexes and a Combinatorial Poincaré Lemma

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, simplicial-complex, discrete-calculus

On the wikipedia page for [conservative vector fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_vector_field#Irrotational_vector_fields) there is a proof sketch given for the following result:

> **Wikipedia**: Let $U$ be open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Then all closed differential $1$-forms are exact if and only if $U$ is simply connected.

I assume there is a combinatorial variant for a finite simplicial complex, but I am not really comfortable with fundamental groups or the Hurewicz isomorphism, and the part of their argument regarding torsion I don't follow, so I was hoping someone could help me fill in the blanks for the following claim:

> **Claim**: Let $K$ be a finite simplicial complex.  Then $K$ is simply connected if and only if $H^1_{\Delta}(K, \mathbb{R})=0$.

The two parts I'm having trouble formalizing are (i) why a trivial fundamental group yields $H_1(K,\mathbb{Z}) = 0$ (which I suspect is trivial), and how I can get the other direction, where I need to go from $H^1(K, \mathbb{R})=0$ to $H_1(K,\mathbb{Z})= 0$.  Why can't torsion be an issue?

Comment: For (i), the first homology group is the abelianization of the fundamental group. For (ii) I suspect the Universal Coeficient Theorem helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Hurewicz theorem states that, for a connected complex
$K$, $H_1(K,\Bbb Z)$ is the Abelianisation of the fundamental
group $\pi_1(K)$. We can have $H_1(K,\Bbb Z)$ trivial if
say $K$ has non-Abelian simple fundamental group.

In the original example for $U$ an open subset of $\Bbb R^2$,
$H_i(U,\Bbb Z)$ never has torsion, so by then universal coefficient theorem,
$H_i(U,\Bbb R)=H_i(U,\Bbb Z)\otimes \Bbb R$.
Also, if $U$ is not simply connected, there is a point in its complement
such that a cycle in $U$ winds about it. That cycle gives a non-zero element of $H_1(U,\Bbb Z)$.

Comment: That's already hugely helpful.  Can you point me to why an open subset has no torsion?  Also, does this mean that the result for complexes is not necessarily true, given one can obviously triangulate things like a Klein bottle?

Comment: Let $C$ be a $1$-cycle in an open subset of $\Bbb R$. Then $C$ is homologous to zero iff its winding numbers about all points in the complement of $U$ are zero. See texts on complex analysis. So if $C$ is homologically non-trivial all positive multiples of it are too.